# how can I use Spring Data JPA bulk select-update not using queryDsl?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, querydsl, bulkupdate

I want to bulk update my data using jpa.

example

> update data set status = '' where id in (xxx, xxx);

I know, I can change using queryDsl.
and I know this way.

> findAll -> update(List)

but I don't want to this two ways.

can I use Jpa bulk select-update not using queryDsl?
Tnanks.

Comment: @BillyFrost  yes, JPQL is well. but I don't want to JPQL. I want to use query method.

Comment: sorry, I mean JPA api. for example- findAll, update, findByXXX.

Comment: I'm sorry to explain this strangely. this is spring data jpa. now I using spring data jpa. and I want to use Query Methods.